# Проблема с парсингом в bs4

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Проблема с bs4
Программа не хочет доставать `data-price`. Возникает ошибка.

```
price2 = answer.select('span[class=normal_price]')
```

здесь пришлось использовать именно так, так как мне нужно что бы `span` содержал только ОДИН тег.
Ниже приложу код, и саму страницу

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

req = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=')
response = BS(req.content, 'html.parser')

for answer in response.select('.market_listing_row_link'):
    href = answer.get('href')
    name2 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_item_name'})
    name = name2.get_text()
    #   name_of_game = answer.select('.market_listing_game_name')
    name_of_game2 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_game_name'})
    name_of_game = name_of_game2.get_text()
    count_on_tm2 = answer.find("span", {'class': 'market_listing_num_listings_qty'})
    count_on_tm = count_on_tm2.get_text()
    price2 = answer.select('span[class=normal_price]')
    price = price2.get('data-price')
    print(name)
    print(name_of_game)
    print(count_on_tm)
    print(price2)
    print(href)
    print('')
```

https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том что

```
answer.select('span[class=normal_price]')
```

возвращает массив, а у массива нет метода `get` поэтому вам надо писать

```
price = price2[0].get('data-price')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. До меня было до ходило бы несколько дней. Огромное тебе спасибо